# Vector Components and Resultant

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors

My sister got this homework that she don't understand, me neither. Can anyone help out?
 Here's the problem:

Give the x-component and y component of the following vectors:

a. A = 7.0 cm, E

b. B = 5.7 cm, S

c. C = 5.5 cm, 30 degrees E of N

d. D = 5.5 cm, 60 degrees S of E

Get the resultant of the four vectors, R = A + B + C + D.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: East is positive x-axis, West is negative x-axis, North is positive y-axis, South is negative y-axis

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us your workings :)

Answer (score 1):

I would interpret it like this: The vector A has a length of 7 cm and points eastwards. If you define North as 0°, E(ast) as 90°, S = 180 ° and so on, you have the length of your vector and the direction. This is all you need for the 2-dim problem. Your vector is given in polar coordinates and you should transform it into cartesian coordinates.

The length of a vector is defined as $r=\sqrt{x²+y²}$, the angle $\varphi $ is given by the tangent: $\tan(\varphi)=\frac{y}{x}$.

This is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just add them up like arrows, tip-to-tail. You can achieve this by summing each component $(x, y)$ of each of the vectors. So, starting through $A$ to $D$ we get:

$$A + B + C + D = (7, 0) + (0, -5.7) + (5.5 \sin(30), 5.5 \cos(30)) + (5.5\cos(60), -5.5\sin(60)),$$

so,

$$R = A + B + C + D = (7, 0) + (0, -5.7) + (2.75, 4.76) + (2.75, ?) = (12.5, ?),$$

where $R$ is your resultant vector. As this is homework I have left out one to complete yourself.